# Using declaration refers into C, which is a base class (alias) of D, but it is not recognized as valid

Tags: templates, c++11, gcc, clang, using-declaration

This looks like an issue in clang (I've already opened a [bug to clang](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=27961)), but I'd like to be sure that I'm not doing a mistake.

Consider the following code:

```
struct B { };

template<typename...>
struct D;

template<typename T, typename U, typename... A>
struct D<T, U, A...>: D<U, A...> {
    using C = D<U, A...>; // (1)
    // using D<U, A...>::D; // (2)
    // using C::C; // (3)
    using C::D; // (4)
};

template<typename T>
struct D<T>: T { using T::T; };

int main() {
    D<int, double, B> d{};
}
```

Lines (2) (if commented out (1) and (4)) and (3) (if commented out (4)) work as expected, while (1) (the example above as it is) gives the following errors:

> 11 : error: dependent using declaration resolved to type without 'typename'
>   using C::D;
>
> [...]
>
> 11 : error: using declaration refers into 'C::', which is not a base class of 'D'
>   using C::D;

Anyway, `C` is an alias of `D<U, A...>`, that is a base class of `D<T, U, A...>`.
As far as I know, that snippet should compile. Am I wrong?

Note that GCC compiles it at least since [v4.8.1](https://godbolt.org/g/dWe4Si) to [v6.1](https://godbolt.org/g/CTa7iT).

Comment: http://wg21.link/CWG2070

Comment: So, it is an issue the fix of which isn't part of the standard yet, right? It mentions it as discussed only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the ticket to clang, it cannot be considered a bug (maybe):

> Clang is following the direction of core issue 2070 (http://wg21.link/cwg2070), which matches the intent of the original proposal (see the end of "Outline of the Solution" in http://wg21.link/n2540). As such, this is working as intended. To inherit a constructor, you need to use the same identifier before and after the ::.